# how to loop through a string and select only uppercase letters without removing spaces?in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query with eloquent Laravel Who selects the people who have birthdays today in My db phpMyAdmin, the detail is that in the query it returns a string with everything and characters, how could I eliminate them, this is My code.

```
public function handle()
    {
        $date = new DateTime();
        $fechahoy = Carbon::today();
        $today = now(); 
        // $fecha_nacimiento = Users::whereDay('fecha_nacimiento', '=', '$today')->whereMonth('fecha_nacimiento', '=', '$today')->get();
        $nombre_cumple = Users::select('name','primer_apellido','segundo_apellido')
        ->whereMonth('fecha_nacimiento', '=', $today->month)
        ->whereDay('fecha_nacimiento', '=', $today->day)->get();
        error_log($nombre_cumple);
        error_log($nombre_cumple[9]->name);
```

This is what the code returns

```
[{"name":"JESUS ADRIAN","primer_apellido":"ALVARADO","segundo_apellido":"LUJANO"},{"name":"KATTIA","primer_apellido":"RAMIREZ","segundo_apellido":"ESPINOZA"}]
```

In the query I thought it would bring me the names of the people who have birthdays today, but it returns a whole string of arrays with characters and I only want the letters in uppercase

Comment: "_This is what the code returns_" That's what gets written to your log I assume? `$nombre_cumple` should be a Collection you can simply loop through

Answer (score 0):

You can loop this collection ($nombre_cumple) to get the names.

```
foreach( $nombre_cumple as $user)
{
   print_r(strtoupper($user->name)); // do whatever you want to do with user name.
}
```